# jQuery: How to restore the initial state of click events in this specific case?

Tags: jquery

This is the code:

```js
let selected_animal = "Animals"

// Hover Function

$("#cats_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Cats");
});

$("#dogs_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Dogs");
});

$("#ducks_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Ducks");
});

$("img").mouseout(function() {
  $("h1").text(selected_animal);
});


// Click Function

$("#cats_image").click(function() {
  selected_animal = "Cats"
  $("h1").text("Cats");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#cats_text").addClass("show");
});

$("#dogs_image").click(function() {
  selected_animal = "Dogs"
  $("h1").text("Dogs");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#dogs_text").addClass("show");
});

$("#ducks_image").click(function() {
  selected_animal = "Ducks"
  $("h1").text("Ducks");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#ducks_text").addClass("show");
});


// White Area Click Function

$("body").click(function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ???
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <h1>Animals</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <img id="cats_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Mackerel_tabby_cat_pair-Hisashi-01.jpg">
  <img id="dogs_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Two_puppies_dogs.jpg">
  <img id="ducks_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/The_pair_of_ducks.jpg">
</main>

<footer>
  <div id="cats_text">Domestic cats are valued by humans for companionship and their ability to hunt rodents.</div>
  <div id="dogs_text">The coats of domestic dogs are of two varieties: "double" being familiar with dogs (as well as wolves) originating from colder climates, made up of a coarse guard.</div>
  <div id="ducks_text">Duck is the common name for numerous species in the waterfowl family Anatidae which also includes swans and geese.</div>
</footer>
```

Everything works how it should work. But if you click now at some point in a white area (where is no text, and no images), the initial status should be restored. Means that then there shouldn't be a footer text, and the h1 should be "Animals". How is it possible to do that?

Would be very thankful for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `return false;` statement to all the click events declaration for each img. And your body event will just change the text and remove Class like this:

```js
$("body").click(function() {
      selected_animal = "Animals";
      $("h1").text(selected_animal);
      $("footer div").removeClass("show");
    });
```

The other declarations should be like this:

```js
$("#ducks_image").click(function() {
      selected_animal = "Ducks"
      $("h1").text("Ducks");
      $("footer div").removeClass("show");
      $("#ducks_text").addClass("show");
      return false;//here is the return statement
    });
```

The `false` actually doesn't let the event to propagate upto `html` tag. Hence if `img` is clicked then `body` will not be clicked and `body` event will not be triggered. It will only be triggered when clicked in white area.